# Network quality related battery discharge

Tags: battery, samsung-galaxy-s-4, battery-life, stock-android

I'm seeing a ridiculous battery drain on my Android/Samsung Galaxy S4 seeming to correlate with network traffic/signal change (see images below). Please keep in mind that the phone sits idly on my desk during the periods in question. It is stock (Android:4.4.2, Kernel: 3.4.0, Hardware: I545.07).

Has anyone had else already solved this issue?

[image: Case one]
[image: Case two]
[image: Case three]

Comment: You sure it's related to signal? Your status bar is plenty icon-laden indicating to me you have alot going on there. I wouldn't look to basic functionality as the culprit - check the other apps running and draining battery as the first and more-likely candidates.

Comment: I am not certain it is signal, but the representative screenshots ( a small sample ) always correlate to a signal quality change - and then a dramatic battery drain. If I turn off my mobile data and leave wifi on (for those same services to leverage), I do not experience the problem. So while I am not certain - I think its very likely. I might be able to attach ADB and view it but who has time for that?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with an S4 mini.  I found the best solution to turn off airplane mode and then turn *on* wifi, which essentially keeps it from searching for a cell signal when one was poor or non-existent.  You can create reminders or macros to do some of this on a non-rooted phone.

Comment: I had considered that kind of solution - but as I'm sure you'll agree - it sucks. If I have my phone in airplane mode, I won't get texts or calls...

Comment: Agreed. How about switch "mobile data" off instead of airplane? Macrodroid will let you create a macro to trigger by location (the office) and turn mobile data off. You then create another trigger for leaving the office and turning mobile data back on. Ideal? No. Some suckage removal? Probably.